# How to enable text wrapping or multi-lines when using \begin{cases}?

Tags: cases

[image]

I am writing a \begin{cases} \end{cases} block, and I need to write something to the left of the case. However, since it is very long, I would like to use multiple lines or text wrapping.

But I cannot figure how this works. Can someone help?

Comment: You can insert a \parbox (specify width) or tabular (specify break points).  It will automatically revert to text mode inside.  [t] will align the first line, [c] will align the center, and [b] will align the last line,

Comment: @JohnKormylo Dear john, I am rather new to this latex. Could you demo?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\vtop` primitive at the left side of the `\cases`, For example in Plain TeX:

```
$$
  \vtop{\hsize=2cm \leftskip=0pt plus 2fil 
        \noindent some text text}
  \cases {a\cr b\cr c}
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments, reproducing the example given.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \parbox[t]{0.7in}{\centering some text text} 
  \begin{cases} a\\ b\\ c \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    some text\\ 
    text
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{cases} a\\ b\\ c \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```